How can souls be the real thing?
If you look at historical records, the concept of a soul has existed long before it was ever "revealed" by any ancient prophet, with tribes and ancient civilizations already coming up with an ethereal substance that connects them together as a species, probably to feel important with respect to animals or to create a connection with their pre-existing deities. In fact, the Jews formally recorded the idea of the soul in their religious texts based on traditional beliefs which had not come from divine inspiration. So, if souls as described in the Bible and prophetic texts are a human invention derived from reason and other social beliefs, then how could this possibly coincide with what is actually true? The "system" for our connection with God and the supernatural world could literally be anything outside our wildest imaginations, and it just so happens that it's exactly the same as how humans had originally believed it to be? Do souls really exist?
But then, if souls don't exist, can heaven or hell even exist either? In fact, those have also existed as concepts since ancient times, and it's clear how their creation by a society could positively benefit it (e.g. an elder telling kids they will suffer eternally if they disobey, lie, steal, etc. and this evolving into widespread belief)...
Without these principles, everything about Christianity falls apart, so where does the reasoning go wrong?
Sorry if this seems a bit anti-religious, but they're genuine doubts of mine.

"from reason and other social beliefs, then how could this possibly coincide with what is actually true" so things derived from reason can't be true?

This would be a much better and more interesting question if "souls as described in the Bible" were accompanied by those scriptural quotations that describe what a soul is.


the Jews formally recorded the idea of the soul in their religious texts based on traditional beliefs which had not come from divine inspiration

Scripture tells us that Adam and Eve, the first-ever humans, talked directly with God. It records many other instances of God communicating with people throughout history, including many instances that predate Moses and the time that Genesis was collected as a single document. We don't know what source or sources Moses used when compiling Genesis; in particular, we don't know that his sources did not include written sources which have since been lost. (Also, the claim that oral records are unreliable is not accurate.)
Divine revelation was present from the beginning of Creation. The idea of beliefs which predate divine inspiration is therefore false.

Do souls really exist?

Scripture says they do, and Scripture, being the inspired word of the infallible and all-knowing God, is the most reliable source of Truth that is available to us.
The rest of your question is thus irrelevant.

God communicated directly with Moses as a man speaks to his friend, by a 'similutude' due to the amount of detailed information that needed to be conveyed. Moses, no doubt, transcribed it all, as a scribe documents dictated speech. Up-voted +1.

This answer tries to clarify

the connection of the concept of "soul" to the metaphysics of a human soul and how it survives in the afterlife,
the relationship between a philosophical theory and the Christian theological teaching on "soul",
the "system" for our connection with God and the supernatural world

What is soul?  For the purpose of this answer, let's define it as the animating principle of a human being, which is an Aristotelian view, representative of your problem of how this concept of "soul" is arrived to by reason through philosophical examination.
What is theology? Theos is God, so theology is a theory of God, but traditionally this discipline uses revealed sources in addition to philosophy.  Christian theology trusts what the Bible says regarding God, and by extension regarding human being, our relationship with God, and how we survive death.

An example of a theology that starts with Aristotelian philosophy but modifies it in the service of Christian Theology is of course Thomism.  Judaism has their own way to adapt Aristotelian philosophy to their Theology.  This by no means obligates a theologian to accept Aristotelian concept of "soul" "as is", but the theologian is free to extend that concept to support the sure teaching that God wants to grant believers eternal life.  So the survival of a soul (understood in Aristotelian way) has to be theorized to support the revealed doctrine of the resurrection of the body.

One 21st-century modern Thomist way (that takes into account findings of neurology, A.I., and philosophy of consciousness) is to believe that the "configuration" of a soul remains in the mind of God (which includes our memory, our identity, our individuating characteristics, etc).  In this theory, when we die, our "soul" dies along with the body, which is consistent with Gen 3:19 ("From dust you came and to dust you shall return").

But to posit some kind of post-mortem consciousness (which is not a doctrine in Protestantism, only in Catholicism and Eastern Orthodox), as well as resurrection of the body (a doctrine by all 3 branches), human beings are at the complete mercy for God to "re-materialize" the configuration stored in the mind of God into either post-mortem consciousness and/or resurrection in a glorified body.


At any rate, theology teaches the possibility for a human being (while living, and, for the 2 branches, while in the intermediate state) to commune with God.  The HOW is not part of the doctrine!  So whatever a Christian theorizes philosophically the constitution of a soul, it really doesn't matter as long as

a living human being believes that God can hear his/her prayer, and
nothing can separate us from God's love (Rom 8:31-39) which presumes a metaphysical entity on our part that can receive that love.

Similarly, the doctrine of heaven and hell STILL works regardless of our philosophical conception of soul.  The HOW is not part of the doctrine.  What's important is the blessed eternal life for the believers or the eternal suffering for the unbelievers, whatever metaphysical form of the blessed or the sufferer.  In addition, Christian doctrine is clear on how the resurrection will look like for the blessed: BODILY (which presumes that "soul" is included, whatever the form is).
I hope the above clarification can help you.

But then why did these same concepts (heaven, hell and soul) exist before the roots of Christianity? My main question was, how could they possibly coincide with reality?

"why did these same concepts (heaven, hell and soul) exist before the roots of Christianity?"  Why not?  There are plenty of religions, each religion posits their own understanding.  The question is: which one is TRUE, and HOW do we know?  Reality is understood THROUGH a theology / religion.  Reality is the given, the theology is the understanding.  Christian revelation is seen as TRUE LIGHT that explains what reality TRULY is.  I don't follow what your problem is just because prior religions (let's pick Egyptian book of the dead) have their own teachings.

It's no coincidence that the Bible teaches that Jesus is "the light of the world".  In the midst of options, we need to see what is true, and because humans are bodily existence, God provides a bodily way (Jesus) to embody that light.  Jesus speaks "I am the way" with a voice that can be heard by a bodily ear, and Jesus provides enough evidence that he comes from the spiritual (non-bodily) realm that no one else can come from, which authenticates Jesus is God incarnate.  So we trust what we hear, and by extension, Christian theology to show us what is TRULY real.

I purposely use the conception of soul example where the soul can die, which does not mean the soul is not "real".  It is our experience of soul that is real, i.e. pointing to God and able to commune with spiritual beings, the soul itself does NOT have to be immaterial for it to be "real".  In this conception, "soul" is an abstraction for humans to theorize, but the ability to commune with God is real, and thus the reality of heaven, hell, post-mortem consciousness, etc.

"One 21st-century modern Thomist..." who says that? The description which follows fundamentally contradicts Thomistic principles. +1 though for mentioning the metaphysical reality of the existence of the soul.

The Jewish and Christian Scriptures do not claim that God has never spoken to other people outside their faiths.

Pharaoh had a true, prophetic dream from God that was interpreted by Joseph, saving many lives.
Job is thought by many to have been the first book of the Bible that was written. Job was neither Jewish nor Christian, yet he was commended by God for his righteousness and God spoke to him. In fact, God's speech to Job is the longest speech delivered by God to any person in the Bible.

This if the concept of the soul arose outside of Israel, that does not rule out its truthfulness.

Good answer, +1. Though if we're being pedantic, Job wasn't Jewish because no one was Jewish at that time. (And, of course, see my Answer. God has been talking to people since Adam and Eve; there is no point in time that predates "divine inspiration".)
